# Mailchimp template only shows first section in yahoo webmail client

Tags: yahoo, mailchimp

I have coded an email template for Mailchimp, and it seems to be working fine in most email clients I've tested (windows mail, mac mail, gmail webclient) - but in yahoo webmail client, it only shows the very first section of the template - the header - and nothing more.

If I send the email to my yahoo address, but display it in Mac Mail, it works. If I email the webpage of the template to my yahoo address (ie, don't go through mailchimp), and view it in the yahoo webmail client, it works. It's only when I send the email through mailchimp, and check it in Yahoo webmail client, that it only shows the first section.

I've tried various things like deleting the top section or various other sections. It usually seems like only one section of the template shows - but I can't seem to find any consistent behaviour, or reason.

Has anyone experienced this before? Did you find the problem/solution? Or, is there an easy way to see what HTML mailchimp generates immediately prior to sending the email, so I can debug that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after much pain, I found the culprit was an invisible character that had somehow ended up in my template. I still don't know what the character is, or does, exactly - but I've now switched on 'Show Hidden Characters' in my text editor!